# TextInputLayout design support library doesn't show setCounterEnable() method android

Tags: android

Thats what I have:

```
TextInputLayout text1 = (TextInputLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.text1);
```

I am trying to do

```
text1.setCounterMaxLength(50);
```

TextInputLayout doesn't have setCounterMaxLength()method. I also tried to do it through xml

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 app:counterEnabled="true"
 app:counterMaxLength="10">
<android:layout_width="wrap_content"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:hint="Username"
 android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
 android:layout_centerVertical="true"
 android:ems="10"
 android:hint="Username" />
</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

It throws below error:

```
Error:(56) No resource identifier found for attribute 'counterEnabled' in package
Error:(56) No resource identifier found for attribute 'counterMaxLength' in package
```

I am using  below gradle dependencies:

```
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.0.1'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1'
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try `23.1.0` instead of `23.0.1`

Comment: Thanks, but I have also tried this. It doesn't work either. I get below exception by using 23.1.0: Error:A problem occurred configuring project.
> A problem occurred configuring project '   > Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ': debugCompile'.
      > Could not find com.android.support:design:23.1.0.
        Searched in the following locations:
            https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/design/23.1.0/design-23.1.0.pom

Comment: > Could not find com.android.support:design:23.1.0.
        Searched in the following locations:
            https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/design/23.1.0/design-23.1.0.pom
            https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/design/23.1.0/design-23.1.0.jar

Comment: /Library/Android/sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/design/23.1.0/design-23.1.0.pom
 /Library/Android/sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/design/23.1.0/design-23.1.0.jar
 /Library/Android/sdk/extras/google/m2repository/com/android/support/design/23.1.0/design-23.1.0.pom
 /Library/Android/sdk/extras/google/m2repository/com/android/support/design/23.1.0/design-23.1.0.jar

Comment: > Could not find com.android.support:design:23.1.0.
        Searched in the following locations:
            https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/design/23.1.0/design-23.1.0.pom
            https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/design/23.1.0/design-23.1.0.jar
 /Library/Android/sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/design/23.1.0/design-23.1.0.pom
 /Library/Android/sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/design/23.1.0/design-23.1.0.jar
 /Library/Android/sdk/extras/google/m2repository/com/android/support/design/23.1.0/design-23.1.0.pom

Comment: Library/Android/sdk/extras/google/m2repository/com/android/support/design/23.1.0/design-23.1.0.jar
        Required by:
            Project :unspecified

Answer (score 2):

First, when you have significant changes to a question, please click the "edit" link below the question and edit the question. Do not pour lots of information into comments.

Second, your Android Repository is out of date, as `23.1.0` is available for all the standard support libraries. Go into your SDK Manager and update the Android Repository, down towards the bottom in the "Extras" area.

Then, you can update `build.gradle` to pull in `23.1.0`, which has your method and attributes.

Answer (score 0):

Try updating the build tools to the latest version in the SDK manager. After that update the `build.gradle`to `compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.1'` and rebuild gradle.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add this in your android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout, `xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"`